# Refresh the content of a <div> that contains the function call to a oracle database

Tags: php, oracle

I have a question with my programming assignment,
I have a fabrication process program that populates the data overtime that means the database value changes every seconds.

I have a function that takes the sum over the data changes which means the sum always changing over time.

Function is like this, (I am using Oracle 11g)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WELTESADMIN.GET_BLDG_SURF(PROJNAME IN VARCHAR)
RETURN NUMBER IS TOTAL_BLDG_SURF NUMBER(15,3);
    BEGIN 
        SELECT SUM(4 * MD.TOTAL_QTY * MD.SURFACE) INTO TOTAL_BLDG_SURF
            FROM MASTER_DRAWING MD WHERE MD.DWG_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' 
            AND MD.PROJECT_NAME = PROJNAME;
            RETURN(TOTAL_BLDG_SURF);
    END;
```

and I am calling tat function in my PHP code like this,

```
$surfaceSumSql = "SELECT GET_BLDG_SURF(:projName) SURFACETOTAL FROM DUAL";
        $surfaceSumParse = oci_parse($conn, $surfaceSumSql);                   
        oci_bind_by_name($surfaceSumParse, ":projName", $_SESSION['cd-dropdown']);
        oci_define_by_name($surfaceSumParse, "SURFACETOTAL", $totalSurfaceSum);
        oci_execute($surfaceSumParse);

<div class="small-box bg-green">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <h3>
                                        <?php echo number_format($totalSurfaceSum,2); ?><sup style="font-size: 20px">M2</sup>
                                    </h3>
                                    <p>
                                        TOTAL PROJECT SURFACE
                                    </p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

My question is how do i make the software refreshes the content of the  every 1 second so that the user will see the value changes over time. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The thing you are looking for can be done using **AJAX Short Polling** but first you should learn to load data using **AJAX**. Google -> basic php ajax tutorial

Comment: Is it better using WebSocket or short Polling ?

Comment: As far as I think, Short Polling is better than WebSockets because WebSockets are not well supported ..